# Batch file to read first line of text that hasn't been used, and then mark as used

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a requirement to, within a windows batch file, read the first available line from a text file, pass it to a variable and mark the name\line as used

An example of the file is below.

apple
pear
orange

The script would start with 'apple', pass 'apple' to a variable to be used later in the script (I know how to do that bit), and then write back that line to read &apple, the '&' works as a marker to say it's been used.

The file would then look like:

&apple
pear
orange

the next time the batch file is run it would take 'pear', pass it to a variable and mark it with a & making it look like:

&apple
&pear
orange

I started by trying to find '&' and then trying to move to the next line, but I'm failing after about 12 hours of trying.  This is what I got so far .. not much:

for /f "tokens=1" %l in ('name.txt') do (Find /v "&" /v "^---- ^$") (For /F %n in (%l) do (set NewName=%n))

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running this on `the.file` would modify each line in turn;

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
type nul > the.file.temp
set last=
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (the.file) do (
    set line=%%A
    if "!line:~0,1!" neq "&" if "!last!" equ "" (
        set last=!line!
        set line=^&!line!
    )
    echo !line! >> the.file.temp
)

echo last value is !last!
type the.file.temp > the.file
```

(If the line does not begin with `&` and the variable `last` is empty, put the line in `last` & modify `line` with a leading `&`. Always append `line` to a temp file, renaming when done)

Comment: I'm really sorry, but this is so above my level of understanding, that I can't understand it put the value (e.g. apple) in a variable, ad if so which one.  If it doesn't I can't work out where to put in in your script. Thanks

Comment: After the last line the value is in `!last!` E.g. `echo value is '!last!'`

Comment: +1 - The solution works well, but it is relatively slow. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13296394/1012053) for a much faster solution.

Answer (score 4):

Alex k. has a good answer that is probably fine for most situations. (I upvoted.)

However, it will corrupt any text containing `!`. That limitation can be fixed by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

The solution is likely to be fast enough for most reasonably sized files. But a FOR loop can become quite slow for large files.

I tested a 190kb file containing 2817 lines, and the Alex K. solution took 20 seconds for one run.

Here is a completely different solution without using any loops that processes the same 190kb file in 0.07 seconds - 285 times faster :)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file=test.txt"
findstr /bv "$ &" "%file%" >"%file%.available"
set "var="
<"%file%.available" set /p "var="
if defined var (
  >"%file%.new" (
    findstr /b "&" "%file%"
    <nul set /p "=&"
    type "%file%.available"
  )
  move /y "%file%.new" "%file%" >nul
)
del "%file%.available"

echo var=!var!
```

***Update:*** As requested in comment, here is a heavily commented version of the code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: Define the file to process
set "file=test.txt"

:: Write the unused lines to a temporary "available" file. We don't want any
:: empty lines, so I strip them out here. There are two regex search strings;
:: the first looks for empty lines, the second for lines starting with &.
:: The /v option means only write lines that don't match either search string.
findstr /bv "$ &" "%file%" >"%file%.available"

:: Read the first available line into a variable
set "var="
<"%file%.available" set /p "var="

:: If var defined, then continue, else we are done
if defined var (

  REM Redirect output to a "new" file. It is more efficient to redirect
  REM the entire block once than it is to redirect each command individulally
  >"%file%.new" (

    REM Write the already used lines to the "new" file
    findstr /b "&" "%file%"

    REM Append the & without a new line
    <nul set /p "=&"

    REM Append the unused lines from the "available" file. The first appended
    REM line is marked as used because of the previously written &
    type "%file%.available"
  )

  REM Replace the original file with the "new" content
  move /y "%file%.new" "%file%" >nul
)

:: Delete the temp "available" file
del "%file%.available"

:: Display the result
echo var=!var!
```

I haven't tested this, but I just realized I could have written the line that writes the available lines to look for lines that start with a character other than `&`:

```
findstr "^[^&]" "%file%" >"%file%.available"
```

Comment: +1 Impressive! But confusing... Any way you could add heavy commenting to explain what's happening, how, when, where... "Teacher my brain is full, can I go now?" :)

Comment: Wow.. Never seen BATCH lines start with < symbol. Great commenting! Wish I could give multiple ++!! Say, why'd it take so long to add the comments? I mean 32 minutes? Did you, like, take time to *breathe*?! ;-D

Comment: @Lizz - Actually you just happened to catch me on-line. I had been watching TV for hours. I just finished watching "The good, the bad, and the ugly" - classic :-)